# Is there a way to increase performance on these two foreach loops?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'm currently working on an application for customers to help update customer information. The Customers query returns minimum 500 results. The CustomerItemList is a separate item list. Both lists contain Customer PK. I need to merge these two lists where the customerPK matches. It's important to note that the customer pk can be listed more than once in the customer item list! The below code snippet works, but is very slow. I'm hoping to update it with linq, but I haven't found anything that increases performance yet.

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
            var Customers = LookupCustomers(CustomerItemList); //returns 500

            foreach (var customer in Customers)
            {
                var CustomerIDList = CustomerItemList.Where(x => x.CustomerPK.Equals(customer.CustomerPK)).ToList(); //returns at least 2 results
                foreach (var CustomerID in CustomerIDList)
                {
                    CustomerID.CustomerPrimaryCard = customer.PrimaryCardID + ", 1";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is this Entity Framework or other ORM?

Comment: Should be customer instead of item, correct?

Comment: correct, I just update that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Customers
    .Join(CustomerItemList, c => c.CustomerPK, i => i.CustomerPK, (c, i) => new { Customer = c, Item = i })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(r => { r.Item.CustomerPrimaryCard = r.Customer.PrimaryCardID + ", 1"; });
```

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
Customers
    .Join(CustomerItemList, c => c.CustomerPK, i => i.CustomerPK, (c, i) => new { Customer = c, Item = i })
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(r => { r.Item.CustomerPrimaryCard = r.Customer.PrimaryCardID + ", 1"; });
```

But parallel processing is best used if you have a large number of results and/or resource-intensive operations. Otherwise, it will actually be slower.

The general idea is to use Set operations.

Comment: Thanks! 

This solution worked perfectly and is increasing my performance time tremendously.

Comment: Don't use `.ToList()` just to get `.ForEach(...)`  This will iterator your set twice.  Just use a regular `foreach` keyword over the `IEnumerable` from `.Join(...)`

Comment: BTW, your `.AsParallel()` will do nothing except maybe get rid of any order within your set.

Answer (score 1):

Try convert your `CustomerItemList` into a dictionary:

```
var customersDict = CustomerItemList.GroupBy(c => c.CustomerPK)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
```

Then in `foreach` use this code:

```
foreach (var customer in Customers)
{
    List<CustomerItem> items; // not sure about elements type of CustomerItemList
    if (!customersDict.TryGetValue(customer.CustomerPK, out items))
        continue;

    foreach (var CustomerID in items)
        CustomerID.CustomerPrimaryCard = customer.PrimaryCardID + ", 1";
}
```

Comment: This will break if there are no items for the customer in the list.

Comment: ToLookup will be better and safer

Comment: The point ASprin was tring to make is instead of doing `.GroupBy(c => c.CustomerPK).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());` you can simplify it to `.ToLookup(c=> c.CustomerPK);` When you use ToLookup you can do the old forech you had because items that fail to look up returns a empty IEnumerable instead of throwing a exception or null.

Answer (score 0):

If your `CustomerItemList` is large, pre-sort it by your search critera `CustomerPK` and use BinarySearch to retrieve the first occurence of the searched item. Start iterating from there and break with the first non-matching `CustomerPK`